no method named `as_fd` found for struct `Async` in the current scope
I am compiling my node with the substrate release branch as polkadot-v0.9.22 and I get the following errors. What is this error and how do I even fix this?
error[E0599]: no method named `as_fd` found for struct `Async` in the current scope
   --> /home/rrr/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/async-process-1.5.0/src/lib.rs:514:16
    |
514 |         self.0.as_fd()
    |                ^^^^^ method not found in `Async<std::process::ChildStdin>`

error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<OwnedFd as TryFrom<Async<std::process::ChildStdin>>>::Error == std::io::Error`
   --> /home/rrr/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/async-process-1.5.0/src/lib.rs:523:17
    |
523 |         value.0.try_into()
    |                 ^^^^^^^^ expected enum `Infallible`, found struct `Error`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `OwnedFd: From<Async<std::process::ChildStdin>>` is not satisfied
   --> /home/rrr/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/async-process-1.5.0/src/lib.rs:523:17
    |
523 |         value.0.try_into()
    |                 ^^^^^^^^ the trait `From<Async<std::process::ChildStdin>>` is not implemented for `OwnedFd`
    |
    = help: the following other types implement trait `From<T>`:
              <OwnedFd as From<File>>
              <OwnedFd as From<PidFd>>
              <OwnedFd as From<TcpListener>>
              <OwnedFd as From<TcpStream>>
              <OwnedFd as From<UdpSocket>>
              <OwnedFd as From<UnixDatagram>>
              <OwnedFd as From<UnixListener>>
              <OwnedFd as From<UnixStream>>
            and 3 others
    = note: required for `Async<std::process::ChildStdin>` to implement `Into<OwnedFd>`
    = note: required for `OwnedFd` to implement `TryFrom<Async<std::process::ChildStdin>>`
    = note: required for `Async<std::process::ChildStdin>` to implement `TryInto<OwnedFd>`

error[E0599]: no method named `as_fd` found for struct `Async` in the current scope
   --> /home/rrr/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/async-process-1.5.0/src/lib.rs:598:16
    |
598 |         self.0.as_fd()
    |                ^^^^^ method not found in `Async<std::process::ChildStdout>`

error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<OwnedFd as TryFrom<Async<std::process::ChildStdout>>>::Error == std::io::Error`
   --> /home/rrr/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/async-process-1.5.0/src/lib.rs:607:17
    |
607 |         value.0.try_into()
    |                 ^^^^^^^^ expected enum `Infallible`, found struct `Error`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `OwnedFd: From<Async<std::process::ChildStdout>>` is not satisfied
   --> /home/rrr/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/async-process-1.5.0/src/lib.rs:607:17
    |
607 |         value.0.try_into()
    |                 ^^^^^^^^ the trait `From<Async<std::process::ChildStdout>>` is not implemented for `OwnedFd`
    |
    = help: the following other types implement trait `From<T>`:
              <OwnedFd as From<File>>
              <OwnedFd as From<PidFd>>
              <OwnedFd as From<TcpListener>>
              <OwnedFd as From<TcpStream>>
              <OwnedFd as From<UdpSocket>>
              <OwnedFd as From<UnixDatagram>>
              <OwnedFd as From<UnixListener>>
              <OwnedFd as From<UnixStream>>
            and 3 others
    = note: required for `Async<std::process::ChildStdout>` to implement `Into<OwnedFd>`
    = note: required for `OwnedFd` to implement `TryFrom<Async<std::process::ChildStdout>>`
    = note: required for `Async<std::process::ChildStdout>` to implement `TryInto<OwnedFd>`

error[E0599]: no method named `as_fd` found for struct `Async` in the current scope
   --> /home/rrr/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/async-process-1.5.0/src/lib.rs:671:16
    |
671 |         self.0.as_fd()
    |                ^^^^^ method not found in `Async<std::process::ChildStderr>`

error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<OwnedFd as TryFrom<Async<std::process::ChildStderr>>>::Error == std::io::Error`
   --> /home/rrr/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/async-process-1.5.0/src/lib.rs:680:17
    |
680 |         value.0.try_into()
    |                 ^^^^^^^^ expected enum `Infallible`, found struct `Error`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `OwnedFd: From<Async<std::process::ChildStderr>>` is not satisfied
   --> /home/rrr/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/async-process-1.5.0/src/lib.rs:680:17
    |
680 |         value.0.try_into()
    |                 ^^^^^^^^ the trait `From<Async<std::process::ChildStderr>>` is not implemented for `OwnedFd`
    |
    = help: the following other types implement trait `From<T>`:
              <OwnedFd as From<File>>
              <OwnedFd as From<PidFd>>
              <OwnedFd as From<TcpListener>>
              <OwnedFd as From<TcpStream>>
              <OwnedFd as From<UdpSocket>>
              <OwnedFd as From<UnixDatagram>>
              <OwnedFd as From<UnixListener>>
              <OwnedFd as From<UnixStream>>
            and 3 others
    = note: required for `Async<std::process::ChildStderr>` to implement `Into<OwnedFd>`
    = note: required for `OwnedFd` to implement `TryFrom<Async<std::process::ChildStderr>>`
    = note: required for `Async<std::process::ChildStderr>` to implement `TryInto<OwnedFd>`


I’m voting to close this question because no response.

Apologies! Missed this out. I think i fixed this by downgrading async-process from v1.5.0 to v1.4.0. You can close this if you want.

Okay, I can reopen the question if you'd like to mark this as the answer.

This is some compile error in a dependency. I would bet that you maybe use a compiler that is too new. Generally I would not recommend to use such an old Polkadot branch. Updating to a newer version should fix it.
